# Python Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I'm solving a design optimization problem for a manufacturing facility that has multiple discrete options for equipment (e.g. select one of `0.5,1,2,5`). The cost `M` is fixed but the quantity `β` of parts is another discrete variable with `n` total units to be constructed. A simplified, minimal example that demonstrates the issue is shown below:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
n = 100
# select one of the Special Ordered Set
α = m.sos1([0.5, 1, 2, 5])
# integer variables
β = m.Array(m.Var,n,integer=True,lb=1,ub=5)
# log transform
δ = [m.log(b) for b in β] 
# matrix
M = np.random.rand(n,n)
# constraints
Mδ = M.dot(δ)
m.Equations([α*x>50 for x in Mδ])
# objective
m.Minimize(α)
# solve
m.solve()
print('α: ', α.value[0])
print('β: ', β)
```

An exhaustive search of all feasible solutions isn't practical with `5^100 x 4 = 3e70` possible feasible solutions. This simplified problem solves in about 30 seconds with ~100 integer variables.

```
 Number of state variables:            205
 Number of total equations: -          102
 Number of slack variables: -          100

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    33.4135999999999      sec
 Objective      :    1.00000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
α:  1.0
β:  [[3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [5.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0] [5.0] [4.0] [4.0]
 [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0]
 [4.0] [4.0] [5.0] [3.0] [1.0] [4.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0]
 [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [4.0] [1.0] [3.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0]
 [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [1.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0] [3.0]
 [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [4.0] [2.0] [3.0] [1.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0]
 [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0] [4.0] [3.0] [3.0]
 [3.0] [2.0] [4.0] [5.0] [4.0] [2.0] [3.0] [4.0] [3.0] [4.0] [1.0] [3.0]
 [5.0] [3.0] [4.0] [5.0]]
```

One potential solution is to terminate the solver when a first feasible integer solution is available rather than iterate until the gap tolerance is met. However, this could return a sub-optimal solution. What are strategies to improve the solution speed?

Comment: I think you can post your question in the `Code Review` SE since this is about optimizing your code

Answer (score 0):

The solver iteration summary can give suggestions on how to improve the solution speed. Here are a few suggestions:

**Initialization**

If the first NLP of the branch and bound (non-integer solution) takes a while to solve then try initializing with the `IPOPT` NLP solver with:

```py
# solve
for i in [3,1]:
    m.options.SOLVER=i
    m.solve()
```

Initialization reduces the time on the first iteration for `APOPT` from 1.57 sec to 0.1 sec to obtain a solution on Iteration 1:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter: 1 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi: 2 Dpth: 0 Lvs: 3 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
Iter: 2 I: -1 Tm: 0.05 NLPi: 0 Dpth: 1 Lvs: 2 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
Iter: 3 I: -1 Tm: 0.09 NLPi: 1 Dpth: 1 Lvs: 1 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
```

but `IPOPT` takes `3.09` sec to find that initial solution so there is no time savings.

**APOPT Solver Options**

There are [APOPT solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) that can help improve the solution speed. If infeasible NLP problems take a disproportionate amount of the solution time, set the `nlp_maximum_iterations` to a lower number to terminate trial solutions that are not converging quickly. The `minlp_branch_method=1` has a positive effect on solution time for this problem as a depth-first search to quickly identify an initial integer solution. This helps eliminate candidate solutions and prune the branch-and-bound tree. One other solver option to try is the `minlp_gap_tol` at a larger tolerance for a successful solution.

```py
m.solver_options = [# nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
```

Set the random seed to give a run-to-run direct comparison with the same random numbers for matrix `M`:

```py
# same random numbers
np.random.seed(0)
```

With the same random numbers, these options improve the solution time from `7.86` sec to `4.87` sec.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# same random numbers
np.random.seed(0)

m.solver_options = [# nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

n = 100
# select one of the Special Ordered Set
α = m.sos1([0.5, 1, 2, 5])
# binary variables
β = m.Array(m.Var,n,integer=True,lb=1,ub=5)
# log transform
δ = [m.log(b) for b in β]
# matrix
M = np.random.rand(n,n)
# constraints
Mδ = M.dot(δ)
m.Equations([α*x>50 for x in Mδ])
# objective
m.Minimize(α)
# solve
m.solve()
print('α: ', α.value[0])
print('β: ', β)
```

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:  1 I:  0 Tm: 1.57 NLPi: 24 Dpth:  0 Lvs:  3 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
Iter:  2 I: -1 Tm: 0.05 NLPi:  0 Dpth:  1 Lvs:  2 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
Iter:  3 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi:  2 Dpth:  1 Lvs:  3 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: NaN
Iter:  4 I:  0 Tm: 0.30 NLPi:  5 Dpth:  2 Lvs:  5 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter:  5 I:  0 Tm: 0.22 NLPi:  4 Dpth:  3 Lvs:  7 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter:  6 I:  0 Tm: 0.16 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  4 Lvs:  9 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter:  7 I:  0 Tm: 0.16 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  5 Lvs: 11 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter:  8 I:  0 Tm: 0.17 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  6 Lvs: 13 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter:  9 I:  0 Tm: 0.16 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  7 Lvs: 15 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 10 I:  0 Tm: 0.17 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  8 Lvs: 17 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 11 I:  0 Tm: 0.15 NLPi:  3 Dpth:  9 Lvs: 18 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 12 I:  0 Tm: 0.16 NLPi:  3 Dpth: 10 Lvs: 20 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 13 I:  0 Tm: 0.20 NLPi:  4 Dpth: 11 Lvs: 22 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 14 I:  0 Tm: 0.25 NLPi:  5 Dpth: 12 Lvs: 24 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 15 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi:  2 Dpth: 13 Lvs: 26 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 16 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi:  2 Dpth: 14 Lvs: 28 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
Iter: 17 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi:  2 Dpth: 15 Lvs: 30 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: NaN
--Integer Solution:   1.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:   7.60E-01 Gap:   2.40E-01
Iter: 18 I:  0 Tm: 0.10 NLPi:  2 Dpth: 16 Lvs: 29 Obj: 1.00E+00 Gap: 2.40E-01
Iter: 19 I: -1 Tm: 0.09 NLPi:  1 Dpth:  2 Lvs:  1 Obj: 7.60E-01 Gap: 2.40E-01
Iter: 20 I:  0 Tm: 0.55 NLPi:  5 Dpth:  1 Lvs:  0 Obj: 5.00E+00 Gap: 2.40E-01
 No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    4.86900000000605      sec
 Objective      :    1.00000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```